# Как убрать левую границу у пункта списка?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Помогите, не могу убрать левую границу у пункта nth-child(1) не помогает

Вот код:

```css
.team__social-item {
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
  background: #fce38a;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 57px;
  border-left: 1px solid #f38181;
}
```

```html
<ul class="team__social">
  <li class="team__social-item">
    <a href="#" class="team__social-link">
      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="team__social-item">
    <a href="#" class="team__social-link">
      <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="team__social-item">
    <a href="#" class="team__social-link">
      <i class="fab fa-pinterest-p"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="team__social-item">
    <a href="#" class="team__social-link">
      <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
  background: #fce38a;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 57px;
  border-left: 1px solid #f38181;
}

li:first-of-type {
  border-left: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Вариант 2

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul{
    display: flex;
}
li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 57px;
    height: 57px;
    background: #fce38a;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 57px;    
}
li + li{
    border-left: 1px solid #f38181;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо, первый вариант сработал, но почему не сработал, nth-child, в чем разница между этими двумя псевдоклассами?

Comment: разница между nth-child и nth-of-type - https://habr.com/post/119139/

Comment: в вашем случае нет разницы между nth-child и nth-of-type - https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/98tLgpdy/

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на `display: inline-block;`

```css
.team__social {
  padding: 0;
}

.team__social::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

.team__social-item {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 57px;
  height: 57px;
  background: #fce38a;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 57px;
  border-left: 1px solid #f38181;
}

.team__social-item:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="team__social">
  <li class="team__social-item">
    <a href="#" class="team__social-link">
      <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="team__social-item">
    <a href="#" class="team__social-link">
      <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="team__social-item">
    <a href="#" class="team__social-link">
      <i class="fab fa-pinterest-p"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="team__social-item">
    <a href="#" class="team__social-link">
      <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```